# Is it safe to cascade hypot()?

Tags: c, math, floating-point

I would like to compute the norm (length) of three- and four-dimensional vectors.  I'm using double-precision floating point numbers and want to be careful to avoid unnecessary overflow or underflow.

The C math library provides `hypot(x,y)` for computing the norm of two-dimensional vectors, being careful to avoid underflow/overflow in intermediate calculations.

My question: Is it safe to use `hypot(x, hypot(y, z))` and `hypot(hypot(w, x), hypot(y, z))` to compute the lengths of three- and four-dimensional vectors, respectively?

Answer (score 3):

It's safe, but it's wasteful: you only need to compute `sqrt()` once, but when you cascade `hypot()`, you will call `sqrt()` for every call to `hypot()`.  Ordinarily I might not be concerned about the performance, but this may *also* degrade the precision of the result.  You could write your own:

```
double hypot3(double x, double y, double z) {
    return sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
}
```

etc.  This will be faster and more accurate.  I don't think anyone would be confused when they see `hypot3()` in your code.

The standard library `hypot()` may have tricks to avoid overflow, but you may not be concerned about it.  Ordinarily, `hypot()` is more accurate than `sqrt(x*x + y*y)`.  See [e_hypot.c](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/a2f34833b1042d5d8eeb263b4cf4caaea138c4ad/sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/e_hypot.c) in the GLibC source code.

Comment: The naive implementation fails for `hypot3(DBL_MAX, 0.0, 0.0)` (overflow),  `hypot3(DBL_MIN, 0.0, 0.0)` (underflow), etc.  As stated in the question, I want to avoid this.

Comment: What is your range of inputs?

Comment: Then you'll use multiple `hypot()` and live with the fact that you are essentially computing `sqrt(x) * sqrt(x)`.  I personally find it somewhat rare to care about values in the 1e100 range or higher, so it is interesting that you care about all possible inputs.

Comment: Note that in either case, you won't have the same precision as `hypot()`.

Comment: you can also normalize x,y,z yourself using frexp and ldexp to protect against over/underflow. Made a bit messier by the fact that frexp gives an exponent of 0 for 0.0, rather than a large negative integer. BTW, in re to precision, chaining hypot (in a tree for more than 3 values) is equal to or better than adding the sums of squares and taking the square root, due to the fact that adding squares of things of different mags leads to more loss of precision than adding the mags of the things. But it's slower...

Answer (score 2):

It safe (almost) to use `hypot(x, hypot(y, z))` and `hypot(hypot(w, x), hypot(y, z))` to compute the lengths of three- and four-dimensional vectors.

C does not strongly specify that `hypot()` *must* work for a `double x, y` that have a finite `double` answer.  It has [weasel words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel_word) of "without undue overflow or underflow".

Yet given that `hypot(x, y)` works, a reasonable `hypot()` implementation will perform  `hypot(hypot(w, x), hypot(y, z))` as needed.  There is only 1 increment (at the low end) /decrement (at the high end) of binary exponent range lost when with 4-D vs. 2-D.

Concerning speed, precision, and range, code profile against `sqrtl((long double) w*w + (long double) x*x + (long double) y*y + (long double) z*z)` as an alternative, but that seems only needed with select coding goals.

Answer (score 1):

I've done some experiments with this sort of thing. In particular I looked at a plain implementation, an implementation using hypots and (a C translation of the reference version of) the BLAS function DNRM2.

I found that as regards over and underflow, the BLAS and hypot implementations were the same (in my tests) and far superior to the plain implementation. As regards time, for high (hundreds) dimensioned vectors, the BLAS was about 6 times slower than the plain, while the hypot was 3 times slower than BLAS. The time differences were a bit smaller for smaller dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Should code not be able to use `hypot()` nor wider precision types, a slow method examines the exponents using `frexp()` and scales the argumnets [@greggo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30199890/is-it-safe-to-cascade-hypot/38981372#comment51394529_30199926).

```
#include <math.h>

double nibot_norm(double w, double x, double y, double z) {
  // Sort the values by some means
  if (fabs(x) < fabs(w)) return nibot_norm(x, w, y, z);
  if (fabs(y) < fabs(x)) return nibot_norm(w, y, x, z);
  if (fabs(z) < fabs(y)) return nibot_norm(w, x, z, y);
  if (z == 0.0) return 0.0;  // all zero case

  // Scale z to exponent half-way 1.0 to MAX_DOUBLE/4
  // and w,x,y the same amount
  int maxi;
  frexp(DBL_MAX, &maxi);
  int zi;
  frexp(z, &zi);
  int pow2scale = (maxi / 2 - 2) - zi;

  // NO precision loss expected so far.
  // except w,x,y may become 0.0 if _far_ less than z
  w = ldexp(w, pow2scale);
  x = ldexp(x, pow2scale);
  y = ldexp(y, pow2scale);
  z = ldexp(z, pow2scale);

  // All finite values in range of squaring except for values 
  // greatly insignificant to z  (e.g. |z| > |x|*1e300)
  double norm = sqrt(((w * w + x * x) + y * y) + z * z);

  // Restore scale
  return ldexp(norm, -pow2scale);
}
```

Test Code

```
#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#ifndef DBL_TRUE_MIN
#define DBL_TRUE_MIN DBL_MIN*DBL_EPSILON
#endif

void nibot_norm_test(double w, double x, double y, double z, double expect) {
  static int dig = DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1;
  printf("     w:%.*e x:%.*e y:%.*e z:%.*e\n", dig, w, dig, x, dig, y, dig, z);
  double norm = nibot_norm(w, x, y, z);
  printf("expect:%.*e\n", dig, expect);
  printf("actual:%.*e\n", dig, norm);
  if (expect != norm) puts("Different");
}

int main(void) {
  nibot_norm_test(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  nibot_norm_test(10 / 7., 4 / 7., 2 / 7., 1 / 7., 11 / 7.);
  nibot_norm_test(DBL_MAX, 0, 0, 0, DBL_MAX);
  nibot_norm_test(DBL_MAX / 2, DBL_MAX / 2, DBL_MAX / 2, DBL_MAX / 2, DBL_MAX);
  nibot_norm_test(DBL_TRUE_MIN, 0, 0, 0, DBL_TRUE_MIN);
  nibot_norm_test(DBL_TRUE_MIN, DBL_TRUE_MIN, DBL_TRUE_MIN,
      DBL_TRUE_MIN, DBL_TRUE_MIN * 2);
  return 0;
}
```

Results

```
     w:0.00000000000000000e+00 x:0.00000000000000000e+00 y:0.00000000000000000e+00 z:0.00000000000000000e+00
expect:0.00000000000000000e+00
actual:0.00000000000000000e+00
     w:1.42857142857142860e+00 x:5.71428571428571397e-01 y:2.85714285714285698e-01 z:1.42857142857142849e-01
expect:1.57142857142857140e+00
actual:1.57142857142857140e+00
     w:1.79769313486231571e+308 x:0.00000000000000000e+00 y:0.00000000000000000e+00 z:0.00000000000000000e+00
expect:1.79769313486231571e+308
actual:1.79769313486231571e+308
     w:8.98846567431157854e+307 x:8.98846567431157854e+307 y:8.98846567431157854e+307 z:8.98846567431157854e+307
expect:1.79769313486231571e+308
actual:1.79769313486231571e+308
     w:4.94065645841246544e-324 x:0.00000000000000000e+00 y:0.00000000000000000e+00 z:0.00000000000000000e+00
expect:4.94065645841246544e-324
actual:4.94065645841246544e-324
     w:4.94065645841246544e-324 x:4.94065645841246544e-324 y:4.94065645841246544e-324 z:4.94065645841246544e-324
expect:9.88131291682493088e-324
actual:9.88131291682493088e-324
```